# Forms of the Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian

The most general form of the Shrodinger equation is $$i \hbar \frac{d}{dt}| \psi(t) \rangle = \hat{H} | \psi(t) \rangle$$ but we also have the Schrodinger equation when projected onto the position basis given as $$i \hbar \psi(r,t) = i \hbar \langle r | \psi(t) \rangle = \langle r | \hat{H}| \psi(t) \rangle = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \psi(r,t) + V \psi(r,t) $$

**Question**: What are the limits of the Shrodinger equation given in the form  $$i \hbar \psi(r,t) = \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \nabla^2 \psi(r,t) + V \psi(r,t).$$ 
For example, apparently the above form of the Shrodinger equation does not accommodate a particle which experience  the Lorentz force $$\vec{F} = q(\vec{E} + \vec{v} \times \vec{B}),$$ since the force cannot be expressed as the gradient of a scalar potential energy function.

Comment: Presumably missing a $\partial_t$ in the third eq.

Comment: http://lampx.tugraz.at/~hadley/ss1/IQHE/cpimf.php

Answer (score 1):

You are right, there are restrictions to the schroedinger's equation, but these restrictions will never arrise due to the choice of a suitable representation. In your example, you have given the schroedinger's equation in a general form, and then afterwards you have choosen the position-representation. In principle, you can do this with every Hamilton-operator that your are given.

However, your problem with the Lorentz-Force begins earlier: The Lorentz-Force isn't s conservative force, as you said, so you can't express the Hamilton Operator with a potential-term. This problem will become appearent, regardless of the representation that you choose, and is solved by the link that Hugh-Mungus posted in the comments.